# Midi Controller Device Names

Tags: midi

For writing a midi (wrapper) library, I'm trying to figure out, where the "name" of a midi device is defined. Is it something given by the device or given by the system that it is connected to?

For instance I'm getting the following output from 'amidi' on a linux machine, to which a midi controller is connected.

```
amidi -l
Dir Device    Name
IO  hw:1,0,0   MIDI 1
```

Its name is always " MIDI 1" (sic!) and I'm not sure if I can assume, that every single device of this vendor/model will have the same name.

Answer (score 4):

For PCI sound cards, the driver knows the name.

For USB devices, the `snd-usb-audio` driver looks into the device's descriptors to get the device name, and appends " MIDI x" to get the MIDI port name. If there is no device name defined, it constructs a default name from the device number, so this looks as if your MIDI controller explicitly returns an empty string. This results in a nonsensical result in your case, but taking this name is the best your library can do.

(Run "`sudo lsusb -v 2>&1 | grep -e iManufacturer -e iProduct`" as root to see what your USB devices declare.)